# Side-effects of disabling auto-commits

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

We are trying to run a transaction using the Wordpress `wpdb` object - not sure if that matters.

```
wpdb->query('BEGIN TRANSACTION');

// Run transaction related queries

if($error) {
   // ROLLBACK
} else {
   // COMMIT
}
```

Now it seems like mysql does this brilliant thing of setting `auto_commit` to `true`, which causes every query after execution to auto commit. We learnt that we can disable this amazing feature by running `SET auto_commit = 0`.

At the end of our query we will be running `SET auto_commit = 1`. My question is that would this affect any other queries being run on the DB at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not every database supports transactions, so PDO needs to run in what is known as "auto-commit" mode when you first open the connection. Auto-commit mode means that every query that you run has its own implicit transaction, if the database supports it, or no transaction if the database doesn't support transactions. If you need a transaction, you must use the PDO::beginTransaction() method to initiate one.
Now guess it is good or bad ?